# find student name less than 50 attendance

Tags: sql

I have a student table where column is `name`, `attendance`, and `date` in which data is entered everyday for the students who attend the class. For example if a student is absent on a day, entry is not made for that particular student for that day.

Finally. I need to find out students name whose `attendance` less than 50.

Comment: To **attend**, results in **attendance** ....

Comment: What did u try? This site is not made to do your homework

Comment: which DBMS are you using ? MySQL, MSSQL, ORACLE? also share the schema details and sample data of student table. You need list of all student to find a student who never attended because you are storing data of those students who are attending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause to aggregate similar student in table and [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) check your condition, to get your desired output.

```
SELECT name, count(name)
FROM student    
GROUP BY column_name 
HAVING count(name)<50;
```

I hope this will help to solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` statements for this.

```
SELECT name FROM student GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) < 50;
```

Please note that above query is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
FROM StudentsTable
WHERE COUNT(name) < 50
```